# Windows server 2016 Active Directory and VirtualBox host on same server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, virtualbox

I know it's not considered best practice having Active Directory Domain Service role and Hyper-V role on same server.

What about VirtualBox?

Can I install VirtualBox on the same physical machine where Active Directory service is running? And then, can I install, as a VirtualBox guest machine, another instance of Windows server 2016 who joins the domain installed on that physical machine?

Comment: `Can I install VirtualBox on the same physical machine where Active Directory service is running?` - Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @joeqwerty Because we have to install another instance of Windows server 2016 on the same server where there is Active Directory Service running.

Comment: I think you might need to explain more why you **need** to do this - there might be another way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The point of not running unrelated services on a domain controller is that it is a machine that controls security for your environment. If it's compromised you will be in big trouble. In that case it doesn't matter a lot whether it's a Microsoft service or a third-party one that allowed someone access they shouldn't have had.

A better approach would be to run a hypervisor directly on the physical server and let the domain controller function (and DNS) run by itself in a VM. Note that you will have a small bootstrapping problem if you run a single hypervisor that's dependent on services that are only available via a VM. It's not an impossible problem, but something to take into consideration.

In a production environment where availability is a factor it's preferable to have multiple domain controllers and DNS servers spread across multiple hypervisors, should something happen to one of them. If your company is small enough, though, the cost of additional hosts may be a lot higher than the cost of lost time due to a power glitch or similar. Just make sure you have good on- and off-site backups so you can restore your data if/when something happens to it.